# Coger solo 1 fila de una relación 1N (TypeORM)

Tags: mysql, nodejs, express, orm, typeorm

Tengo una relacion 1-N entre Users y Tokens.

Un usuario puede tener multiples tokens al mismo tiempo, pero un token solo puede ser de un usuario.

Con TypeORM me gustaría añadir el **ULTIMO** token (No borrado) a la query. Pero solo el ultimo de los N que puede tener.

```
    const query = this.usersRepository.createQueryBuilder('users')

        .select(['users', 'tokens'])
        .leftJoin('users.tokens', 'tokens')

        .skip(paginateUsersDTO.skip) // 0 by default
        .take(paginateUsersDTO.take) // 10 by default

        .orderBy('users.' + paginateUsersDTO.order as string, paginateUsersDTO.direction)
```

El resultado de esta query sería...

```
    "users": [
        {
            "user_id": 1,
            "user_email": "example@example.com",
            "user_password": null,
            "user_first_name": "Example",
            "user_last_name": "Example",
            "user_created_at": "2022-12-29T21:46:40.000Z",
            "user_updated_at": null,
            "user_archived_at": null,
            "user_deleted_at": null,
            "tokens": [] // Incluyendo aquí todos los tokens no borrados
         }
```

*Pero en Tokens solo querría ver el ultimo, eso quiere decir a diferencia de lo que hay:*

1. **Coger solo 1**
2. **Ordenar por ID - DESC**

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener solo el último `token` *(no borrado)* asociado a un usuario, podrías agregar una condición adicional a la `query`, para filtrar solo los `tokens` con un `id` máximo y ordenarlos en orden descendente. El código podría ser algo similar a esto:

```
const query = this.usersRepository.createQueryBuilder('users')
        .select(['users', 'tokens'])
        .leftJoin('users.tokens', 'tokens')
        .where('tokens.deleted_at IS NULL') // solo tokens sin borrar
        .orderBy('tokens.id', 'DESC')
        .addOrderBy('users.' + paginateUsersDTO.order as string, paginateUsersDTO.direction)
        .skip(paginateUsersDTO.skip)
        .take(paginateUsersDTO.take)
        .groupBy('users.id')
        .addGroupBy('tokens.user_id')
        .having('MAX(tokens.id) = tokens.id') // solo el token con el máximo id
```